# AjaxResponse() always wrapped in a <textarea>

Tags: 8, ajax

In a custom controller, I'm returning an AjaxResponse like so:

```
    $response = new AjaxResponse();
    $selector = '.segment-set-wrapper';
    $response->addCommand(new ReplaceCommand($selector, $form));
    return $response;
```

Where `$form` is a render array. However, instead of coming through as JSON with a set of commands, it comes through in a `<textarea>` element containing the string of json e.g. below:

[image]

Any idea what is going on here?

**EDIT**

Adding ajax code:

```
 var ajax_url = '/personalized_paragraphs/ajax/get_reactions';
          var request = $.ajax({
            url: ajax_url,
            method: "POST",
            data: segment_set_id,
            dataType: "html"
          });

          request.done(function( data ) {
            var $wrapper = $submit_btn.closest('.segment-set-wrapper');
            $wrapper.replaceWith(data);
          });
```

Comment: It's for security to prevent code from getting executed. The Drupal AJAX API handles both the wrapping and unwrapping, so if you're facing a problem, it's likely a result of a misunderstanding about how to use the API. If you add an explanation as to what you're trying to do, and what's got you tripped up, maybe someone can provide some specific assistance.

Comment: I added my ajax code to the question if that helps show what I'm doing more

Comment: And what's the problem?

Comment: The problem is that drupal isn't unwrapping the `<textarea>` and executing the commands and the ajax response is just  displaying a <textarea> element on the page with the commands string inside it

Comment: ah it appears that the `dataType` in the ajax request was the issue

Comment: You're doubling down here. You're returning an ajax command to replace some html, but then in javascript you're trying to catch the response, as html, and replace the contents of some html with the contents of the response. Pick one or the other.

Comment: The dataType was the issue. That should be left empty.